# Getting spotify link back python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I've tried using this function in Python in order to get a link back from spotify:

```
import os
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def makeRequestToSpotify(songname):
    encodedname = urllib.parse.quote_plus(songname)
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=" + encodedname+"&type=track"                                                                                                                             "
    content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(content.readall().decode('utf-8'))
    songLink = data["tracks"]["items"][0]["externalurls"]["spotify"]
    print(songLink)
def getMusicFilesFromFolder(afolder):
    extensions = [".mp3",".wma",".aac",".m4a"]
    filenames = []
    for x in os.walk(afolder):
        for file in x[2]:
            file_name, filext = os.path.splitext(file)
            for ext in extensions:
                if filext == ext:
                    filenames.append(file_name)
                    break
    for file in filenames:
        makeRequestToSpotify(file)
    print(filenames)

def buttonClick():
    file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    getMusicFilesFromFolder(file_path)
#User Interface
root = Tk()
root.title("Music Repository with Spotify")
root.geometry("600x600")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
chooseFileButton = Button(app, command=buttonClick, text = "Choose a Folder")
chooseFileButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Which gives me an `index out of range`-error.

I am looking to get the link to each song in the folder back from this program

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that when i try to run it, it says that the list index is out of range

Comment: `data["tracks"]["items"]` in response is probably empty. Can you please show us [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: import os
   import urllib.parse
   import urllib.request
   import json
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter import filedialog

Comment: disregard that, accidentally hit enter

Comment: Could you please provide a sample request and the exact error message? I just tried some queries and did not got an index error but an key error on `externalurls`. Please keep in mind that lists/arrays are unordered, so basically, their order could vary. This could raise key errors since the zero-th element in the list/array could change and does not need to have the key `externalurls`. So, besides your index-error this could probably be another thing to think about.

Comment: okay ive figured it out, in the api (this will make you all laugh) its not externalurls, its external_urls

Comment: after that change it gave me the links no problem